# spring json not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I created a controller with method handler as

```
    @RequestMapping( value = {"/membersjson"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public @ResponseBody String getMembers(Model model) {
                List<Member> members = memberService.getMembers();
                model.addAttribute("members",members);
                return "jsontemplate";
            }
```

---

```
<bean id="jsontemplate"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
```

I expect the out put to be in json but instead the output is "jsontemplate" instead. Can some one please explain the reason. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MappingJacksonJsonView`, or any other view or view resolver bean, is irrelevant when you're using `@ResponseBody`. Instead, Spring will try to convert the return value of your method directly into a response. In this case, it's decided to turn it into a String response.

First make, sure you've declared `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your context, and that [Jackson is available on the classpath](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). Also ensure that the browser is sending `application/json` in its `Accept` header.

Comment: I found that 

<mvc:annotation-driven />

@RequestMapping( value = {"/membersjson"},method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
 public @ResponseBody List<Member> getMembers(Model model) {
  List<Member> members = memberService.getMembers();
  return members;
 }
started working. so my question is without the tag below it is working. then what is the significance of below said tag and also what is the real significance of ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.
<bean id="jsontemplate"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />

Comment: @bhadram: As I said, views and view resolvers are not used when you use `@ResponseBody`. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be returning the string `"jsontemplate"`; you should return either the `List<Member>` or the `Model`. The json mapping should occur automatically.

Comment: I've got similar code in one of apps - I just return the `List<Member>`.